# using toLowerCase to find matches in arrays with a for-loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have a function that iterates over one array and compares each value to the values of another array to find matches.

I'm trying to use toLowerCase() to remove grammar discrepancies between the two.

**Javascript**

```
match: function(array1, array2) {
        counter = 0;
        if (array1.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
                    if (array1[i].toLowerCase() === array2[j].toLowerCase()) {
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (array1 === state.forbidden) {
                return array1.length - counter;
            }

            else {
                return counter;
            }
        }

        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Line 6 is what's relevant for this question.  Match is a method inside the object 'nutrients' and is called nutrients.match(array1, array2);

This seems to work for array1, but not for array 2 because I get the following error message:

**Error Message**

```
Uncaught TypeError: array2[j].toLowerCase is not a function
```

I'm guessing this is due to the *types* of arrays I'm passing into this function but I can't put my finger on why it doesn't work.

The function gets called using a for-loop in the following way:

**Javascript**

```
loop: function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < state.greens.length; i++) {
        nutrients.match(state.desired, state.greens[i].ingredients)
},
```

Loop is a method stored within an object called 'total' and is called by 'total.loop()'

So for some reason state.greens[someNumber].ingredients[someNumber].toLowerCase() is not being recognized as a function.

However, if I try and perform this same operation in the console it comes out correctly:

[image: console]

So I'm not sure where the error is in the code.

Comment: What if the arrays are of different lengths? If one is shorter than the other you're calling `toLowerCase` on `undefined`.

Comment: @tadman - astute observation but the first array that's being iterated over will always be shorter than the second it's being compared to.

Comment: Have you logged your values to the console in the loop? That would seem like it would be your first step in troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing

```
if (array1[i].toString().toLowerCase() === array2[j].toString().toLowerCase())
```

It's possible the value in the array isn't being represented as a String and therefore it has no `.toLowerCase()` method.